# Docx table to mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I've many docx files with tables used as "database"  I'am on web app using flask and mongodb as db ... Can anyone help me to know the steps to transform docx tables into mongodb collection.

Answer (score 1):

## Alternative

The data within the Word tables had to come from somewhere.  You may be better off pulling the data from there instead of the DOCX documents.

## Steps

1. Copy+Paste into Excel
2. Save as a CSV
3. import using available tools

## Notes

Some tools might be available to import an Excel file into a database.  This will allow you to "Save as Excel" instead of "Save as CSV".

If you need to automate the "Copy+Paste into Excel" step, you will need to write the code yourself.  (eg Apache POI)  I don't know how easy it is to identify tables in a Word document.  If you want, you can search the internet to see if someone has done this already.

Most likely, you'll need to process the data into a more appropriate form.  This is just standard [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) processing.

1. **Extract** the data into staging table (all columns are VARCHAR)
2. Validate data (correct DATE format, correct spelling of Dimensional data, etc.)
3. **Transform** the data into the correct data types
4. More data validation (numbers are within range, etc.)
5. **Load** the data into the actual table
6. Final data validation (ie the database `Constraints`)

Make sure your code is sufficiently instrumented.  We ran into a problem with our process.  Once the debug code was turned on, it took us <2min to realize that some of the data wasn't loading because someone misspelled "mouse".  If the data in your DOCX tables is "hand written", you will have a lot of these types of errors.

There will be a lot of code.  Make sure the code is under the control of a Code Repository.

Finally, you need to pray that the Authors kept to a specific format.  If not, you may need to customize the code for each unique format.  If they are all different, you may be better off hiring some interns to manually translate the data into a common Excel format (or web form).  This is what we wound up doing; and we only loaded data for current project (not all data was loaded). All new data started off in a Web Form.

**PS** My process was Excel files into a common set of Oracle DB tables.  Not exactly your situation, but the concept should be the same.

Comment: Thanks for replying... after reading many documentation i found a good solution using pandas , python-docx and pymongo . NO need to copy past yo csv ... Thanks again ✌✌